# Is there a bijective holomorphic function from the upper half plane (or the unit disc) to $H_1=\{z \text{ }|\text{ } 0<\text{Im}(z)<1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions

I am looking for a bijective holomorphic function from the upper half plane to $H_1=\{z \text{ }|\text{ } 0<\text{Im}(z)<1\}$.

Context:

Let $D$ be the unit open ball and $D_{1/2}(-1/2)$ be the open ball of radius $1/2$ around $z=-1/2$. I am trying to find a bijective holomorphic function from $D$ to $D-\overline{D_{1/2}(-1/2)}$.

My idea:

(1) The function $$f:z\mapsto \frac{i-z}{i+z}$$
is a bijective holomorphic function between the upper half plane $H$ and D.

(2) The function $f$ maps the the horizontal line $\text{Im}(z)=C$ to the circle of radius $\frac{1}{C+1}$ centered at $(-\frac{C}{C+1}, 0)$.

(3) From (2) it follows that $H_2=\{z \text{ }|\text{ } \text{Im}(z)\geq 1\}$ is mapped to $\overline{D_{1/2}(-1/2)}$ under $f$. Therefore $H\setminus H_2$ is mapped to $D-\overline{D_{1/2}(-1/2)}$. But $H\setminus H_2=H_1$. If we can find a bijective holomorphic function between $H$ and $H_1$, we are done.

How to find such a function?

Edit:

If we can find a bijective holomorphic function $g$ from $D$ to $H_1$, then the function $f\circ g$ will be a function from $D$ to $D-\overline{D_{1/2}(-1/2)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *existence* of such a mapping is guaranteed by the Riemann mapping
theorem, since both the upper halfplane and the strip $H_1$ are
simply connected and not equal to $\Bbb C$.

For a *concrete* mapping, start with an analytic branch of the logarithm
in the upper halfplane, e.g.

$$
  \log z = \log |z| + i \arg z \text{ with } 0 < \arg z < \pi \, .
$$

Comment: how to proceed further?

Comment: @R_Squared: The logarithm maps the upper halfplane to the strip $\{z \mid 0<\operatorname{Im}(z)<\pi\}$. It only remains to compose that with a multiplication $ z \mapsto z / \pi$ to get a conformal mapping from the upper halfplane to the strip $H_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem).

Comment: I would like to understand why the downvote...

Comment: Me too. Not to mention the attempt to close your answer.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud OP here. I did not downvote.